# Is there a way to retrive client id and call back url from the entries in remote access by just knowing login details

Tags: rest-api, remote-access

Is there a way to retrieve client id and call back url from the entries in Setup -> Develop -> Remote Access by just knowing login details?

Like if I want my desktop app to be dynamic and should be used across instances/organizations, how can I use the rest api by just the login details provided by the user?

Based on the login details provided, should I pull the metadata api (if so how to do that using c#? any examples/links?) and create the remote access and query the client id?? if so how to query the client id??

I know my question is similar to this, but the purpose is different :-
[Can i query the Remote access object to get consumer key and consumer secret?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/can-i-query-the-remote-access-object-to-get-consumer-key-and-consumer-secret)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but you don't need to, your connected apps (or remote access) settings are automatically shared and are usable across different instances/organizations.

Comment: oh Thanks @superfell do you mean to say that If i have a remote access created in one organization, can i connect to some other organization by just changing the login information and using the same consumer key and consumer secret created in my organization?

Comment: yes, you don't need a different consumer key/secret for each org.

Comment: These settings are global as @superfell says, one thing to be wary of though is that they are cached, changes can take a few minutes to take effect which can cause a lot of grief when you're trying to debug things!